# ElasticSearch MultiMatch fields boosting doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: elasticsearch, field, match, keyword

I'm trying to do a keyword search in ElasticSearch. I was originally using this:

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "Susan Sloan",
                                "default_operator": "AND"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, my clients want matches in the first_name and last_name fields to have preference over matches in other fields, such as family members; they didn't like that results with Name = "John Smith" and Spouse = "Susan Sloan" were being shown before Name = "Susan Sloan". So I tried changing it to a multimatch query with greatest boosts on the first_name and last_name field.

```
{
  "query": {
      "filtered": {
          "query": {
              "bool": {
                  "must": [
                      {
                          "multi_match": {
                              "fields": [
                                  "first_name^9",
                                  "last_name^9",
                                  "collection.name^7",
                                  "collection.category.name^7",
                                  "record_type.name^7",
                                  "location.city.name^7",
                                  "location.region.name^7",
                                  "location.country.name^7",
                                  "location.country.name^7",
                                  "relationships.first_name^7",
                                  "relationships.last_name^7",
                                  "attributes.name^1",
                                  "original_text^1"
                              ],
                              "query": "Susan Sloan",
                              "operator": "AND",
                              "type": "cross_fields"
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

However, the boosts don't seem to be doing anything. Even though I have records with first_name = "Susan" and last_name = "Sloan", the first result I get is "Abel Conant," with "Susan" and "Sloan" appearing in the original_text field.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `multi_match` of type `cross_fields`:

```
"query": "Susan Sloan",
"operator": "AND",
"type": "cross_fields"
```

Comment: I added that but I'm still getting results with original_text matches first. Edited my query in my original post

Comment: Then I think you need to test this bit of your query separately and see how it works out of the larger query.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding "type": "cross_fields", I also had to add "analyzer": "standard"

Comment: Well, I assumed the default settings.